# Dynamic Function Calling From a Different File - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dynamic

I have 2 python files. One file has all of the functions, the other file has a function which calls functions from the first file. Here is a simplified version of what I have.

file1.py

```
def one():
        print("Hello World")
def two():
        print("Salutations Earth")
def three():
        print("Greetings World")
```

file2.py

```
import file1
function_id = input("Which function would you like? Please enter(one, two or three): ")
file1.function_id()
```

Clearly, this is not going to work because there is no function named 'function_id' in file1. However, I am not sure how to call the functions from file1 dynamically. I looked on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09v4BfM5wAg&t=217s) and one of the videos suggested to use eval() but it did not work for me. Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file1.py, add a function dictionary like this:

```
function_dict = {'one':one, 'two':two, 'three':three}
```

Then in file2.py, replace `file1.function_id()` with this:

```
file1.function_dict[function_id]()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr()` on the module `file1`

```
import file1

function_name = input("Which function would you like? Please enter(one, two or three): ")
function = getattr(file1, function_name, None)

if function:
    function()
else:
    print(f"No such function: {function}")
```

Note: executing arbitrary user input is not secure.